# How to extract specific bits from an offset

Tags: c, bit, masking, byte-shifting

Im attempting to create an assembler in c of a sorts in which i take an input from a file that contains a command, in this case `branchifequal` i then take its opcode which is `10` so `byte[0] = 0xA0` and then i get the register for the next 4 bits and then the register for the next 4 but then how do i process the offset? assuming that command is `branchifequal r1 r2 8` then the hand assembly should be `A1 20 00 08`. This is done i know by checking the top 4 bits of the address offset which are 0's and then the bottom 16 bits which are `0000 0000 0000 1000` i believe. which should convert to `00 08` in hex. How can i get this while checking the last 4 bits in the second byte and the 2 bits in the 3rd byte and then the last 2 bits in the 4th byte is just simply the hex value itself which is done in my code below. I have this same issue for my `jump` command as well.

**PR1.C**

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    char *ltrim(char *s) {
        while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') s++;
        return s;
    }

    char getRegister(char *text) {
        if (*text == 'r' || *text=='R') text++;
        return atoi(text);
    }

    char getHex(char *text){
        int number = (int)strtol(text, NULL, 16);
        char reservednum[5];
        if(number <= 0xFFFF){
            sprintf(&reservednum[0], "%04x", number);
        }
        return atoi(reservednum);
    }

    int assembleLine(char *text, unsigned char* bytes) {
        text = ltrim(text);
        char *keyWord = strtok(text," ");
        if (strcmp("add",keyWord) == 0) {
            bytes[0] = 0x10;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL," ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("subtract", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x50;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("and", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x20;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("divide", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x30;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("multiply", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x40;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("or", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x60;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("halt", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x00;
            bytes[1] = 0x00;
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("return", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x70;
            bytes[1] = 0x00;
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("addimmediate", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x90;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("interrupt", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x80;
            bytes[0] |= getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = 0x00;
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("push", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x70;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = 0x40;
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("pop", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0x70;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = 0x80;
            return 2;
        }
        else if(strcmp("jump", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0xC0;
            bytes[1] = 0x00;
            bytes[2] = 0x00;
            bytes[3] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 4;
        }
        else if(strcmp("branchifequal", keyWord) == 0){
            bytes[0] = 0xA0;
            bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
            bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4;
            bytes[2] = 0x00;
            bytes[3] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
            return 4;
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        FILE *src = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        FILE *dst = fopen(argv[2],"w");
        while (!feof(src)) {
            unsigned char bytes[4];
            char line[1000];
            if (NULL != fgets(line, 1000, src)) {
                printf ("read: %s\n",line);
                int byteCount = assembleLine(line,bytes);
                fwrite(bytes,byteCount,1,dst);
            }
        }
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's too much to read to find out what you'd like to know specifically and where you stumbled. You might like to [edit] your question to make a [example] with given input, received output, and expected output - or you search the web for other assemblers' sources to peek into them, in example [this](http://bodo4all.fortunecity.ws/atari/a2.html).

Comment: @Shift_left: `[assembler]` is a tag synonym for `[assembly]`, and this is a question about writing an assembler.  It's a very over-complicated context for just asking how to get some bits of an `unsigned int`  into another `unsigned int` with a shift + mask, but merely removing the `[assembly]` tag doesn't really improve the question.